# Including Model Form Nested in Inline Formset (Django)

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I need a way to include a form for a model ("Contact") in an inline formset for a model that includes its foreign key ("Location"). See details below.

I have a Location model.

```
class Location(models.Model):
   description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   contact = models.ForeignKey('Contact')
   customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
   address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have an inline formset for this model.

```
LocationFormset = forms.modelformset_factory(
   models.Location,
   form=LocationForm,
   extra=2,
)

LocationInlineFormset = forms.inlineformset_factory(
   models.Customer,
   models.Location,
   extra=2,
   fields=(
      'description',
      'contact',
      'address',
   ),
   formset=LocationFormset,
   min_num=1,
)
```

I also have a Customer model and a Contact model (as indicated in the Location model). Here is the code for the Contact model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This allows me to select a Customer object and navigate to an input page where I can not only change the Customer but also change all the Locations associated with that Customer. Additionally, I want to be able to modify the Contact associated with the location on this input page. How can I do that? Ideally, I'd like to include the contact forms in the inline formset with the Location.

Comment: ''Simple is better than complex'' line from Zen of Python has persuaded me not to go this way once I tried a similar things. I would definitely be interested in proper solutions.

Comment: Heh. Fair. I wonder if orchestrating a separate Contact form not implemented inline along with the Location formset wouldn't be more complex, though... in any case, I'd be happy to hear from someone who thinks I'm on the wrong track and should make different design choices, too.